# Provide discount to preferred customer with Satchmo?

Tags: python, django, satchmo

I am new to Satchmo -- picked it up because I needed payment processing for site subscriptions and physical product.

My site will have two classes of users: paid subscribers and free users. Both can order a 
physical product. Paid subscribers get an automatic discount on all orders.

I don't see a configuration for this in the admin. (Discount looks like it would apply to all users. If I'm missing something here, let me know.)

So what's the best place to automatically override the price depending on the user class? The displayed price should show up, say, 10% less for subscribers everywhere in the site, not just at the checkout.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the tiered pricing module

Comment: For reference, here's the link: http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/svn/shipping.html#tiered